# RowCategoryBinding cannot find symbol

Tags: android, android-databinding

**Error Message**:

```
C:\FWE\Android\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\test\app\databinding\RowCategoryBinding.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
     import com.test.app.Models;

symbol:   class Models

location: package com.test.app
```

About **RowCategoryBinding.java:14**, it contains this

```
import com.test.app.Models;
```

I get the error if I put the `CategoriesModel.java` file inside Models folder

```
com.test.app
|
--- Adapters
--- Activites
--- Fragments
--- Models
    |
    --- CategoriesModel.java
--- Interfaces
--- Utils
--- ViewModels
```

But if I moved the `CategoriesModel.java` file outside Models, then the app will work without the error. What is the reason?

```
com.test.app
|
--- Adapters
--- Activites
--- Fragments
--- Models
--- Interfaces
--- Utils
--- ViewModels
--- CategoriesModel.java
```

Comment: When moving your `CategoriesModel.java`, are you changing the package to `com.test.app.Models`? or is it the old one `com.test.app` ?

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 If I put the `CategoriesModel.java` file inside the `Models` folder the line 14 in the `RowCategoryBinding.java` file will become like this `import com.test.app.Models;`, But if I put `CategoriesModel.java` file outside `Models` folder the line 14 in the `RowCategoryBinding.java` file will become like this `import com.test.app.CategoryModel;`, I tried to change `import com.test.app.Models;` to `import com.test.app.Models.CategoriesModel;` but it is still return to `import com.test.app.Models;`. Is everything clear?

Comment: Please share the content of your `row_category` xml file where your object is being bound and the package declaration of the class `CategoriesModel` (at the top, starting with **package**, not **import**).

Comment: This design for test only, Check from code -> https://i.postimg.cc/FHwTscS1/Untitled.png

Comment: @hiddeneyes02  I get an error message like above message when I try to run the project, I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 5):

**Android DataBinding** does not allow package first letter to be capital.

Change the folder name from `Models` to `models` and the package from  `com.test.app.Models` to `com.test.app.models`, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: It's worked with me, They must say the error clearly in the message to save our time, Thank you.

Comment: It tells me, You may award your bounty worth reputation in 11 hours. Just wait 11 hour to accept your answer :)

Comment: No worries, you welcome :)

Comment: thanks, man I was spent 6 hours and did so many changes, but nothing worked for me, finally I got the real solution.